# Installing Google Play Store in android emulator

Tags: linux, android

I am trying to install Play Store in AVD emulator. `Google APIS build` And it fails over and over. So I started searching for solutions. But none of them worked.

Reason? here it is

```
android@Debian-101-buster-64-minimal:~/Downloads$ adb install 'Google Play Store_v17.1.16-all [0] [PR] 274697545_apkpure.com.apk'
adb: failed to install Google Play Store_v17.1.16-all [0] [PR] 274697545_apkpure.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.android.vending signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
android@Debian-101-buster-64-minimal:~/Downloads$
```

Ok. A package is already installed with package name `com.android.vending` and that is definitely not Play store

Then what is it? I found that too!

```
android@Debian-101-buster-64-minimal:~$ adb shell pm path com.android.vending
package:/system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk
```

**Output of dumpsys**

```
    android@Debian-101-buster-64-minimal:~$ adb shell dumpsys package com.android.vending
Service Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService:
        dbab1b8 com.android.vending/.licensing.LicensingService filter 2371e08
          Action: "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService"
          AutoVerify=false

Permissions:
  Permission [com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE] (6f3eb91):
    sourcePackage=com.android.vending
    uid=10055 gids=null type=0 prot=normal
    perm=Permission{ac7aaf6 com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE}
    packageSetting=PackageSetting{d5eeef7 com.android.vending/10055}

Key Set Manager:
  [com.android.vending]
      Signing KeySets: 4

Packages:
  Package [com.android.vending] (d5eeef7):
    userId=10055
    pkg=Package{8453164 com.android.vending}
    codePath=/system/app/LicenseChecker
    resourcePath=/system/app/LicenseChecker
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/system/app/LicenseChecker/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=1801 minSdk=25 targetSdk=25
    versionName=1.8
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=2
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{1daafcd com.android.vending}
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    privateFlags=[ RESIZEABLE_ACTIVITIES ]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.android.vending
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2019-04-12 22:25:12
    firstInstallTime=2019-04-12 22:25:12
    lastUpdateTime=2019-04-12 22:25:12
    signatures=PackageSignatures{13b8082 [ef3d224c]}
    installPermissionsFixed=false installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    declared permissions:
      com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE: prot=normal, INSTALLED
    requested permissions:
      android.permission.INTERNET
      android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
      com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH
      com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.android
      com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
    install permissions:
      android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS: granted=true
      com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES: granted=true
      com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH: granted=true
      android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
      com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.android: granted=true
    User 0: ceDataInode=114773 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=1
      gids=[3003]
      runtime permissions:


Dexopt state:
  [com.android.vending]
    Instruction Set: x86
      path: /system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk
      status: /system/app/LicenseChecker/oat/x86/LicenseChecker.odex [compilation_filter=speed, status=kOatUpToDate]


Compiler stats:
  [com.android.vending]
    (No recorded stats)
android@Debian-101-buster-64-minimal:~$
```

And this package is just impossible to remove/uninstall!

I tried overriding this with playstore app 
**from Open Gapps and Apkpure**

Every attempt was failure.  I got the Icon for one time but it'll keep crashing.

**How can i install the play store app in the Google APIS build in AVD emulator**

**I need to use it instead of Play Store build**

Comment: The Google Play Store has officially since several years been preinstalled in the Android Emulator. While it's hard to install in some emulators, it is easy to have for API 24 and above by just selecting from the AVD manager an emulator that already has Google Play. See [link1](https://proandroiddev.com/install-google-play-store-in-an-android-emulator-82cd183fefed) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593738/is-google-play-store-supported-in-avd-emulators). Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

The Google Play Store has officially since several years been preinstalled
in the Android Emulator. While it's hard to install in some emulators,
it is easy to have for API 24 and above by just selecting from the
AVD manager an emulator that already has Google Play.

In the Android Studio AVD Manager choose a virtual device configuration
that has the Google Play store icon next to it, and then select one of the system images that have the label "Google Play". See this release note: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html.

[image: Android Studio AVD Manager with Google Play Store support]

---

The process of installing the Play Store in emulators where it is
not pre-installed is described in the article
[Install Google Play Store in an Android Emulator](https://proandroiddev.com/install-google-play-store-in-an-android-emulator-82cd183fefed).

The following is a summary of the article:

- Download the Google Play packages from
  [The Open GApps Project](https://opengapps.org/)

  [image]
- Unzip the file and extract the highlighted from the Core folder:

  [image]
- To decompress these `tar.lz` files may require installing the
  `lzip` package, then use the command:

  ```
  tar -xf vending-x86.tar.lz
  ```

  The end-result would be:

  [image]
- Check the privileged apps directory for missing APKs:

  ```
  adb shell
  ls system/priv-app
  ```

  [image]

  In the above image the APKs related to Google services are already
  installed, so we only need to install the APK from the `vending-x86`
  folder with the name `Phonesky.apk`.
- Exit the emulator with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- Push this APK to the emulator:

  ```
  $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator @avd_name -writable-system
  adb remount
  adb push ~/Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app/
  adb shell stop && adb shell start
  ```
- The Google Play Store icon should now be in the apps drawer.

Comment: My situation was I thought I needed Play Store with root, but that turned out to not be the case. So in my case, I was able to just use the non-root build that already has Play Store. So the bounty doesnt really apply anymore. However this is a good answer, so you get it. Thanks